# How to update MYSQL table from HTML form with single column of checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, sql-update

I have a MYSQL table named 'orders' that I want to update from a single column of checkboxes in an html form. The code within the form is `<input type='checkbox' name='completed[]' value='';>`

I've looked around for a long time to see how I could submit this form and update my database with this single line of code. In other words, the column of checkboxes consists only of this code block, but there is a checkbox at the end of each row. I know that only the checked boxes will be returned in the `$_POST['completed']` array.

How does one go about updating a mysql table with only one such code block? The update code is this:

```
update = "UPDATE orders SET completed='$completed' WHERE completed=0;";
```

Then

```
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysql_error()); //update or error
```

Comment: Correction: the code got cut from above: ..."<td><input type='checkbox' name='completed[]' value='';" ."></td></tr>"

Comment: Can you properly format your code please?

Comment: I'm only adding the relevant parts of code.

Comment: you still need to properly format it...

Comment: Would you like all of it?  Being new to Stackoverflow, I will say it isn't always easy to add all of it.

Comment: format means indenting it properly so we can actually view the code how it should be (rather than just plain text)

Comment: Would you like me to attempt at doing it for you? :-)

Comment: //part of form - "</td>". "<td><input type='checkbox' name='completed[]' value='';" ."></td></tr>";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  //if the submit button is clicked
{ $update = "UPDATE orders SET completed='$completed' WHERE completed=0;"; $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysql_error()); //update or error

Comment: Sure.  You may be more familiar with this forum and submitting questions.

Comment: Just updated it :) please check your suggested edits

Comment: @Caelan Grgurovic - thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Probable answer:

```
$completed = implode(",", $completed);
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET completed='1' WHERE completed=0 AND orders.id IN ($completed)";
```

assuming your $_POST['completed'] has ids of orders which are completed and completed column has only boolean values.

Comment: Thank you!  It works, with this change:  $sql = "UPDATE orders SET completed='1' WHERE completed=0 AND orders.orderID IN ($completed)"; ; My auto-incrementing, primary key is orderID. I searched a long time - so thanks again!!!

Comment: that's why i wrote probable answer because i didn't know your schema..you're welcome...can you please accept my answer as it worked for you?